# Is there a general way to match a non-greedy Regex from right to left?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I know that there are some similar questions that already have been answered, but from what I understood, they were too specific, in order to be of any use for my problem. I also thought this might be interesting to anybody facing a similar problem in the future since a possible solution to **this** problem will most probably not be able to rely on any special characters, but solely on alpha-numeric characters.
[Link to the regex on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/5trQBZ/1)
If the link doesn't work, here's what I want to do:
I want to extract

```
Hello I want this to be matched World
```

from this string:

```
blablabla Hello blablablabla blablabla Hello blablabla blablabla blablabla Hello I want this to be matched World blablabla blablablablablablablablablablablabla
```

in the shortest possible fashion. The problem here is that my regex will match from the very first occurence of *Hello*, which results in

```
Hello blablablabla blablabla Hello blablabla blablabla blablabla Hello I want this to be matched World
```

My problem is I don't know how many *Hellos* might occur between the first *Hello* and the *Hello* right before *I want this...*
Does anybody know an elegant solution for this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use [`Hello(?:(?!Hello).)*?World`](https://regex101.com/r/5trQBZ/2). Or [`.*(Hello.*World)`](https://regex101.com/r/5trQBZ/3)

Comment: What do you mean by *I want to extract `Hello I want this to be matched World`*? If you already have the string what's the point of extracting it? do you want the position or do you want everything between latest `hello` and first `world`?

Comment: "hello", something, "World" without any "hello" between them. You should post it as answer @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: @Cid Those 2 have already been posted. No need to duplicate.

Comment: Thanks! Just to make sure I really understand the pattern:
Hello(?:any string not containig Hello)repeat as many times as necessary World? 
Did I understand it correctly? It works in this simple example, and I reckon it'd also work with bigger streams. Thanks!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew. I'm very sorry, but I have another question that takes this case a bit further. It'd be amazing if you could once again help with your regex expertise. 
I have this text:
text startkeyword [1]: content. More text, another startkeyword [2]: content more text startkeyword [3]: WANTED CONTENT endkeyword. End of text
I want to extract "WANTED CONTENT". Now it's pretty similar, to my previous question, but note that the digits are changing in the brackets which I could not resolve... Any ideas? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try something, post a real question.

Comment: Alright. I thought it's bad practice, since this probably also qualifies as duplicate...